# geofence and if app terminated local notification can push when user arrived company

Tags: react-native

we would like to **push local notification** after user **arrived boundary company.**
so which library should we use. one more think if user **terminate the app,** app can **push notification** when user arrived company.I try to use https://github.com/eddieowens/react-native-boundary and https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use geo-fence for sure.

[mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) not have geo-fence feature [according to its README file](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation#geofencing) so you can't use the library for this purpose.

I have used [transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) to make exactly the same thing, it works with no issue, but it's not free.

[react-native-boundary](https://github.com/eddieowens/react-native-boundary) is free, but not support. According to open GitHub issues, it has some problems, repo owner not supporting the library for almost 2-3 years. You can still solve a lot of problems with open PRs. I didn't use it, but if you want to go with free, I suggest you examine it.

**EDIT:** I make it with `react-native-boundary`, check below code:

Install dependencies:

```sh
# install permissions library
npm i react-native-permissions@3.x

# install push-notification library
npm i react-native-push-notification@8.x

# install forked react-native-boundary
npm i github:teambitvictory/react-native-boundary#b4d143406b41e866754b5a5fd0275bbd42949ab8
```

Don't forget to follow installation instructions after installing these libraries!

Add below permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

**NOTE:** It's not documented, but you need to add for `react-native-boundary`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

**index.js:**

```js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import PushNotification, {Importance} from 'react-native-push-notification';
import Boundary, {Events} from 'react-native-boundary';

PushNotification.createChannel(
  {
    channelId: 'boundary-demo',
    channelName: 'Boundary Channel',
    channelDescription: 'A channel to categorise your notifications',
    playSound: false,
    soundName: 'default',
    importance: Importance.HIGH,
    vibrate: true,
  },
  created => console.log(`Is notification channel created: ${created}`),
);

Boundary.on(Events.ENTER, id => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId: 'boundary-demo',
    title: 'ENTER SIGNAL',
    message: `On Enter to ${id} in background`,
    importance: 'max',
    priority: 'max',
    ignoreInForeground: false,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
  });
});

Boundary.on(Events.EXIT, id => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId: 'boundary-demo',
    title: 'EXIT SIGNAL',
    message: `On Exit from ${id} in background`,
    importance: 'max',
    priority: 'max',
    ignoreInForeground: false,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
  });
});

const addGeofences = () => {
  Boundary.add({
    lat: 48.86059355484915,
    lng: 2.2908871400126194,
    radius: 200, // in meters
    id: 'eiffel-tower-bridge',
  })
    .then(() => console.log('[BACKGROUND] - Geofence added!'))
    .catch(e => console.error('[BACKGROUND] - Error:', e));
};

const onAfterRebootHeadlessTask = () => async () => {
  addGeofences();
};

Boundary.onReRegisterRequired(onAfterRebootHeadlessTask);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

**App.js:**

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import Boundary, {Events} from 'react-native-boundary';
import Permissions, {PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    handlePermissions();
  }, []);

  const handlePermissions = () => {
    const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';

    if (isAndroid) handleAndroidPermissions();
  };

  const handleAndroidPermissions = () => {
    Permissions.request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).then(
      fineLocationStatus => {
        switch (fineLocationStatus) {
          case RESULTS.GRANTED:
          case RESULTS.LIMITED:
            Permissions.request(
              PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
            ).then(backgroundLocationStatus => {
              switch (backgroundLocationStatus) {
                case RESULTS.GRANTED:
                case RESULTS.LIMITED:
                  handleLocationAllowed();
                  break;
                default:
                  console.log(
                    'ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION ->',
                    backgroundLocationStatus,
                  );
                  break;
              }
            });
            break;
          default:
            console.log('ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ->', fineLocationStatus);
            break;
        }
      },
    );
  };

  const handleLocationAllowed = () => {
    Boundary.add({
      lat: 48.86059355484915,
      lng: 2.2908871400126194,
      radius: 200, // in meters
      id: 'eiffel-tower-bridge',
    })
      .then(() => console.log('[ACTIVE] - Geofence added!'))
      .catch(e => console.error('[ACTIVE] - Error:', e));
  };

  return </>;
};

export default App;
```

It worked on Android 10 and 11. It's not tested in iOS.